# VSCodeでメソッド、クラス名に色をつける方法はあるか？

Tags: vscode, エディタ

VSCodeを利用しています。
コードの可読性を高めるために、メソッド、クラス名に色がついていればありがたいと思っているのですが、そんな便利なプラグインをご存知の方教えて頂けませんでしょうか。

Comment: 使っている言語、環境について教えて頂けますか？VSCodeでは、一般的な言語やデフォルトの設定だとメソッドやクラス名に色が付くと思うのですが……

Comment: Rubyを使っています。殆どデフォルトで使用していますが、付かないです・・・

Comment: Rubyのコードだと認識されていないのではないでしょうか？右下にプレーンテキストなどと表示されているかと思いますので、そこをクリックしてRubyを選択するとどうでしょうか？

Comment: 右下ではRubyを選択しておりますが、それでも、色は変わらないです・・・